# How to disable wordpress page rewrite rule?

Tags: plugins, permalinks, rewrite-rules

I am having a problem with some rewrite rules. I am using a plugin that makes requests like this:
`/pluginname?nonce=123456789&action=submit`

the problem with this is that my wp installation takes the part up to `&` as a variable itself `q=/pluginname?nonce=123456789` which it is not supposed to do...

I tried using a broader rewrite rule like this
`add_rewrite_rule( "pluginname/?(.*)", 'index.php?$matches[1]', 'top' );`
but it does not work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was caused by the nginx rewrite rules, I thought I checked them but eventually I missed the most obvious one :s